# running python jobs in sequence

Tags: python, job-scheduling

I have to run a a list of Python jobs one by one after the successful completion of  each job.

How can I accomplish this in development environment, I know I can use a scheduler in production environment?

FOr example:

module1.py
module2.py
module3.py
module4.py
module5.py

I need to run module1.py then after its successful completion need to trigger module2, then module3..

I have heard of CRON scheduler, Can I install it in windows environment and set it up?

Also, Im on windows environment and use Pydev to develop my applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows or *nix or Mac OS, it's a single command line like this:

```
module1.py && module2.py && module3.py && module4.py && module5.py
```

A scheduler like cron will help you not at all, because it won't avoid running the third job if the second failed, etc.  The above will.

Comment: Windows CMD supports && too, which is the OS that OP's using.

Comment: @JohnZwinck ...although Windows doesn't support the shebang hack, so you'll need `python module1.py && python module2.py`, etc.

Comment: No prob. More interesting finding, the token's supported in CMD, but not in PowerShell, I'm a bit surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Just run them one after each other:

```
python module1.py; python module2.py; python module3.py
```

If you want to stop on the first unsuccesful module execution:

```
python module1.py && python module2.py && python module3.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the cron in windows task scheduler is there ,before that write batch file write all commands to run python programs one by one and put it for task scheduler, 
It works